# Настройка корневой директории WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains

При запуске отладки, IDE принимает корневую директорию проекта за корневую директорию сайта. Как указать ей, что корень сайта - это поддиректория *www*?
Нужно чтобы сайт открывался не *http://localhost:63342/counter/www/index.html*, а *http://localhost:63342/index.html*.

[image: Собственно оно]

Comment: убрать из `URL` `/counter/www` ?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Она тогда в корне проекта начинает index.html искать. 404 короче

Comment: Дак не указывай вообще `index.html`. У меня дак вообще просто `url` стоит `http://localhost:8080/application/main`. И все отлично работало, когда в последний раз проверял. Там же плагин нужен он JB

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев ide тогда все файлы ищет в корневой директории проекта GET http://localhost:63342/counter/tpl/pagetwo.html 404 (Not Found). Уже всё облазил, и сайт jetbrains тоже -- понять не могу

Comment: давайте с самого начала, какую цель преследуете, что хотите получить?

Comment: Чтобы при дебаггинге в браузере открывался локалхост, корневой директорией которого являлась подпапка проекта www.

Comment: ничего не пойму, не указывайте в url `counter/www`, если у вас сервер вернет все как надо, у вас все и запустится. Ну у меня все запускается. При это нужен плагин для браузера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроенный вебсервер в WebStorm всегда использует `http://localhost:63342/<project root>` в качестве web path проекта. Это нужно для того, чтобы поддерживать возможность одновременной работы с несколькими проектами. Перенастроить его так, чтобы можно было использовать просто `http://localhost:63342` (для того, чтобы можно было использовать URL  и запросы, начинающиеся со `/`), нельзя. Но можно отредактировать hosts таким образом, чтобы можно было использовать `http://<project_name>:<port>`. См. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8988#comment=27-577559